# Netlify - Are deployment files case sensitive?

Tags: webpack, node-modules, netlify

I've been working on a storybook and it works locally and on a dev server but when I deploy to Netlify - I get the following:

```
10:16:05 AM: ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap' in '/opt/build/repo/src/Components'
ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
10:16:05 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
10:16:06 AM: ERR!  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap' in '/opt/build/repo/src/Components'
ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at eval (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
10:16:06 AM: ERR!     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
10:16:06 AM: ERR!
10:16:06 AM: ​
10:16:06 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:16:06 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
10:16:06 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:16:06 AM: ​
10:16:07 AM:   Error message
10:16:07 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build-storybook (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
10:16:07 AM: ​
10:16:07 AM:   Error location
10:16:07 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
10:16:07 AM:   npm run build-storybook
10:16:07 AM: ​
10:16:07 AM:   Resolved config
10:16:07 AM:   build:
10:16:07 AM:     command: npm run build-storybook
10:16:07 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
10:16:07 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/storybook-static
10:16:07 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
10:16:07 AM: Caching artifacts
10:16:07 AM: Started saving node modules
10:16:07 AM: Finished saving node modules
10:16:07 AM: Started saving build plugins
10:16:07 AM: Finished saving build plugins
10:16:07 AM: Started saving yarn cache
10:16:07 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
10:16:07 AM: Started saving pip cache
10:16:07 AM: Finished saving pip cache
10:16:08 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Started saving rust rustup cache
10:16:08 AM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
10:16:08 AM: Started saving go dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
10:16:08 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
10:16:08 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:16:08 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m17.059383274s
```

Are these files being flagged case sensitive? I'm not sure why these are being flagged and causing errors.

I'm quite new to storybook and Netlify and can't find any docs indicating about formatting etc

Answer (score 0):

Linux treats files and folder names as case-sensitive. So, `~/Netlify` is not the same as `~/netlify`. Netlify uses an Ubuntu-based Docker container, thus, the same limitation (/ feature?) applies there too.

Thus, it's always recommended to save the files and import them using the same case. This is explained in detail on Netlify Forums: https://answers.netlify.com/t/10754